# enumerate queries in sheets of an excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need a vba macro to enumerate the queries on each worksheet of a workbook.

Can you provide example code?

Jerry E

Comment: You'll need to give us a bit more to go on there, champ.  What kind of queries?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Dim aSheet As Worksheet
For Each aSheet In Worksheets

    Dim aQueryTable As QueryTable

    For Each aQueryTable In aSheet.QueryTables

      ' Do something with aQueryTable, e.g.
        MsgBox aQueryTable.Name

    Next aQueryTable

Next aSheet
```

Comment: I am talking about queries that get external data. I just need to get a list of these queries by worksheet name.

Comment: Hi Jerry, So I changed the answer. Did that help?